# instafeed does not load all images on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, instafeedjs

Am sure this must have been answered but I will ask as I have searched

I have implemented instafeed and it loads the images, also when I click show more, it loads the next set of images, then when I click it one more time it doesn't work

```
   var loadButton = document.getElementById('load-more');
   var userFeed = new Instafeed({
         get: 'user',
         userId: '???',
         clientId: '???',
         accessToken: '???',
         resolution: "standard_resolution",
         useHttp: "true",
         template: '<a data-fancybox="images" data-caption="{{caption}}" href="{{image}}"><img class="fancybox" src="{{image}}" /></a>',            
         sortBy: 'most-recent',
         limit: 12,
         /*links:false,*/
         target: "instafeed",
         /*after: function() {
         // disable button if no more results to load
         if (!this.hasNext()) {
            loadButton.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
         }
        }*/

    });

    // bind the load more button
    /*loadButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        userFeed.next();
    });*/


      // bind the load more button
      loadButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        userFeed.next();
      });

      userFeed.run();
```

below is my html

```
<div id="instafeed" class="row text-center"></div>
    </section>
        <section class="pt-medium pb-medium">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                        <a class="btn default large" id="load-more">Show More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

and css

```
#instafeed {
   min-width: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   overflow: auto;
}
#instafeed img {
   width: 16.5%;
   height: auto;
   display: inline-block;
   padding:2px;
   opacity:0.8;
   filter:alpha(opacity=80);
}

#instafeed img:hover {
   opacity:1;
   filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 468px)
{

   #instafeed img {
      width: 50%;

   }
}
```

I know someone would have solved it and might not be much of a question but it doesn't hurt to help out

Thank you

Comment: I just tried your code and it works. I removed  the client id `clientId: '???'`, and used version 1.4.1 of instafeedjs.

Comment: @Thomas okay will try it again

Comment: @Thomas ... Hi Thomas.. what exactly did you do, because it still isnt working for me... one i click show more, it displays the next set of photos, but if click it again to show more it doesn't work...please tell me what you did...    also this is the version of instafeed am using <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/instafeed.js/1.4.1/instafeed.min.js"></script>